# Find $ \ f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb C$ such that $f(n)= -f(-n+m)$ for $m\in \mathbb Z \setminus 3\mathbb Z$ and $n\in \mathbb Z$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, functions, examples-counterexamples

> Can we expect to find no-zero function  $ \ f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb C$ such that $f(n)= -f(-n+m)$ for $m\in \mathbb Z \setminus 3\mathbb Z$ and $n\in \mathbb Z$?

**Edit**: the example in my mind is: $f(n)=(-1)^n= (e^{\pi i})^n$, this satisfy the above situation if we take $m\in \mathbb Z \setminus 2\mathbb Z.$ I'm willing to generalize the property of $f$ for $m\in \mathbb Z \setminus 3\mathbb Z.$

Comment: If $n \notin 3\mathbb{Z}$, then we would have $f(n)= -f(-n+2n)$, which implies $f(n)=0$ for all $n \notin 3\mathbb{Z}$.  What about $n \in 3\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Dzoooks: Thanks. But how can we take $m=2n$? ($m\in \mathbb Z \setminus 3\mathbb Z$)

Comment: @Somos:Thanks. the example in my mind is: $f(n)=(-1)^n$, this satisfy the above situation if we take $m\in \mathbb Z \setminus 2\mathbb Z.$ I'm willing to generalize the property of $f$ for $m\in \mathbb Z \setminus 3\mathbb Z.$ Thanks .

Comment: @Somos: I've edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Somos: I'm guessing that maybe I have to choose constant $c$ such that $f(n)=(e^{\pi i})^{cn}$ will work? Thanks.

Comment: @MathLearner $n \notin 3\mathbb{Z} \implies 2n \notin 3\mathbb{Z} $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\, q(n, m) := f(n) + f(-n + m). \,$ Now we are given that $\,0 = q(x,y) \,$ for all $\,x,y \in \mathbb Z\,$ where
 $\,y \ne 3z.\,$ 
Given $\, n \in \mathbb Z\,,$ $\,n \ne 3z,\,$ let $\,m=2n\,$ implying $\,0 = f(n) + f(n) \,$ and $\, 0 = f(n).\,$
If $\,n = 3z,\,$ let  $\,m=2n+1\,$ also implying $\,0 = f(n) + f(n+1)\,$ but since  $\, n+1 \ne 3z\,$ we just proved $\, 0 = f(n+1) \,$ implying
$\, 0 = f(n).$ There are many other ways to use the given equations.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the condition to $n=0$ and all authorized $m$:

\begin{align*}f(0)&=-f(1)\\&=-f(2)\\&=-f(4)\\&=-f(5)\\&=-f(7)\\&\ldots\end{align*}

So $f$ assumes the same value on all numbers that are not multiples of $3$.

Now do the same with $n=1$.
\begin{align*}f(1)&=-f(0)\\&=-f(1)\\&=-f(3)\\&=-f(4)\\&=-f(6)\\&\ldots\end{align*}

Now $f$ assumes the same value on all numbers that are not congruent to $2\bmod 3$.

Therefore $f$ has to be constant. Moreover, the second line above tells you that $f(1)=0$.